# PHP and Javascript Webservice

Tags: php, javascript, web-services

By using javascript am trying to cal a webservice.That service return response as follows..

```
<envelope>
<date_time>
Test', callbackTest  Wednesday, March 31, 2010 2:28:55 AM
</date_time>
</envelope>
```

I am using firefox as browser to execute the application.Thats why after creating the object of `XMLHttpRequest` try to read as follows

```
_xmlDoc.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('date_time')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

But it is showing output like undefined.please help me to solve this problem.What is actual problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something has changed with Firefox 3.6.2 
Before I upgraded

`myRequest.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('car')`

was returning a list of nodes, with 3.6.2, nothing. In my case the response starts with

`<xml version="1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes">`

Turns out I had â in my data. It was wrapped in CDATA so I thought I was safe. I'm sure it was fine prior to 3.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do a getElementsByTagName() on a response object. Can you try it on the firebug command line first (since you said you are using firefox)?

Answer (score 0):

Does the response start with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

or somethig similar? That may cause problems.  What do you get from `.responseText`?

Also, are you sure `firstChild` will get you the text node? have you tried `nodeValue` directly on `_xmlDoc.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('date_time')[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

Store this output in one `variable` and try this,

```
 $var=service output,
 $date_time=$var->envelope->date_time;
```

now try `getElementsByTagName` on this `$date_time` variable.